# Paypal smart button - Error scenario testing

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

How to simulate error scenarios in paypal smart buttons, and can I get error in JSON format in onError method in paypal smart button. I want `issue` and `descriptopn` of the error in onError method.

Answer (score 0):

If you [use the server-side front-end](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) to call routes on your server, and in turn [call the v2/checkout/orders API from your server](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/), negative testing can be done with those underlying APIs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/sandbox/request-headers/

I'm not aware of ways to trigger errors with just a client-side integration.

Comment: Thanks for your response I am using client-side integration

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the error scenario then just pass that Invoice id which you used earlier for creating order request.

In on error function, you would not get any Json response but just a simple message showing a capture payment error.